# Explain shows index doesnt working but i have an index

Tags: mysql, index, query, explain

The query in MySQL is:

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED 
SELECT id,
       username,
       name,
       last_name,
       IF(friend IS NOT NULL,1,0) as friend,
       activated,
       if(private=1 AND IF(friend IS NOT NULL,1,0)=1,0,private) as private 
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT CASE WHEN sender='asdf10e84b5fd1b1' 
                        THEN receiver
                        WHEN receiver='asdf10e84b5fd1b1' 
                        THEN sender
                        END AS friend
            FROM `friendship` 
            WHERE (   sender='asdf10e84b5fd1b1' 
                   OR receiver='asdf10e84b5fd1b1') 
              and accepted=1 ) as f ON friend=id 
WHERE activated=1 
ORDER BY friend DESC LIMIT 100
```

And the EXPLAIN EXTENDED says this:
[image]

So in the users table i have this indexes

[image: Indexes]

And the great problem and why i'm using indexes in this problem is because the query is large and the time is 4 sec so when 10,000 users are checking the same the query is slow x10000.

Help me pls
I forgot. The index for users as showed in the first image arent working for this query. You know what im doing bad?

**UPDATE:**

THE CREATE TABLE FOR users is:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `photo` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `birth_date` date NOT NULL,
  `country_code` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `verification_code` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `activated` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `access_token` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `notifications` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `private` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `blue_keys` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `orange_keys` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `playID` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `languaje` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'es',
  `first_login` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `tutos_viewed` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `usuarioIndice` (`username`),
  KEY `tutosViewed_Users` (`tutos_viewed`),
  KEY `userIndex` (`username`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

And the SHOW CREATE TABLE for friendship is

```
CREATE TABLE `friendship` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sender` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `receiver` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `accepted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `blocked` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `friendshipIndex` (`sender`),
  KEY `friendshipBlockedIndice` (`blocked`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2132 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Comment: 1) Show CREATE TABLE for both tables 2) Re-write your query to UNION, avoid subquery and OR in conditions

Comment: Please post TEXT results of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE users; and B) SHOW CREATE TABLE friendship; .

Comment: Thanks guys, the update with the show create table for both tables is in the first text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OR` does not optimize well.  The usual workaround is to reformulate the query to be the `UNION` of multiple `SELECTs` to look for the alternatives.  However, your situation might work better with a second `LEFT JOIN` and `COALESCE()`.

```
SELECT ..., COALESCE(r.sender, s.receiver), ...
    FROM ...
    LEFT JOIN ... AS r WHERE receiver = '...'
    LEFT JOIN ... AS s WHERE sender = '...'
```

Side notes:

- What the heck is the `id` that needs to be varchar(250)?
- There are two identical indexes on `username`; drop one.
- Switch from MyISAM to InnoDB.  Virtually all arguments for MyISAM are "old wives' tales".